# Anchor smart contract where two parties pays the contract and one of them get's the amount

Tags: blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

i'm new to solana development and working on a personal project using the anchor framework.

I fould some resources like solana escrow example and some youtube videos on solana PDA but not able to understand it completely. What i want to achive is:

Let's sat there are two players A & B, both pay same amount (ex: 0.01 SOL) to the contract, based on a condition or i invoke a function (not sure how it's done) one of the player is paid the amount (winner).

How can i achive this using the solana (Anchor), i would really appreciate some resource.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple things going on here -

1. Think of a PDA, 'Program Derived Address', as an account address derived from the address of your program and whatever you salt it with, instead of a random address. This is useful for storing some data that you'd like to be able to grab later without having to remember the address, and rather just needing to remember what you salt this with. In your case, you'd likely want to create an account with a PDA salted with some kind of GameID or player (for instance, player A creates a game, and you generate a PDA with your program address and player A's pubkey).
2. [PaulX's Escrow Program](https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/) is a excellent resource, however he is not using Anchor framework and is instead implementing it natively, which sounds out of scope for what you're working on.

I think my [dutch token auction](https://github.com/reeslabree/dutch-token-auction) program may be of some use for you, as far as PDA's go. Additionally, check out the Solana Cookbook, or more specifically the section on [sending SOL](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol), which is a method within the SystemProgram.

Solana/Anchor is awesome, but it's difficult without scouring the docs. The Solana Cookbook and the [Anchor Discord Server](http://discord.gg/ZCHmqvXgDw) are your friends!